# Why am I getting this error when trying to use sed command to delete string?

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed

I am trying to use `sed` to delete a string from a given file. The string to be removed is stored in `password`. Here is what I have
`sed -i "s/$password//g"  shadowCopy.txt`

It keeps telling me 
`sed: -e expression #1, char 0: no previous regular expression`

I understand that it is yelling at me for the blank in the spot designated for the replacement regular expression, but I don't want to replace it with anything. Lots of looking online says that I'm doing it the way i should be. Any guesses?

I have also tried  `blank=""`
                    `sed -i "s/$password/$blank/g" shadowCopy.txt` which gives me the same error. I have also looked at maybe using `awk` somehow, but cant figure out a way. Really any suggestion as to a way to delete a string in a file will satisfy

EDIT: Using the suggestion below my code is as follows

```
    #Retrieve the root password hash from shadowCopy
    password= awk -F: '$1=="root" {print $2}' shadowCopy.txt


    #Remove the root password
    pw="$password" perl -pe 'BEGIN { $search = quotemeta($ENV{pw}); } s/$search//g' shadowCopy.txt
```

and my output is

```
    $1$aj/Pot/V$H4A7chbz7rfsRIrdL7GO61 //This is the password
    root:$1$aj/Pot/V$H4A7chbz7rfsRIrdL7GO61:16469:0:99999:7:::
    bin:*:16229:0:99999:7:::
```

Why is the password being printed out? And obviously when the file contents are dumped to show the changes, the password is still there. If i add `echo $password` nothing prints so clearly it isn't being properly intialized. Obviously the code in my assignment line works somewhat as it prints out what i'm wanting but it isnt storing it in the variable

RESOLVED: `cp shadowCopy.txt shadowCopy.txt~ && awk  'BEGIN{FS=OFS=":"} $1=="root"{$2=""}1' shadowCopy.txt~ > shadowCopy.txt && rm shadowCopy.txt~` is what actually ended up doing it for me. In case anyone in the future cares to know

Comment: Did you mean `password=$(awk -F: '$1=="root" {print $2}' shadowCopy.txt)`? As it stands, this would run the awk command in an environment with the `password` variable explicitly set to nothing.

Comment: If you have GNU awk 4.1.0 or later, you can use `awk -i inplace rest as before`.

Comment: `cp shadowCopy.txt shadowCopy.txt~ && awk blabla shadowCopy.txt~ > shadowCopy.txt && rm shadowCopy.txt~` works in lieu of inplace editing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that sed cannot operate on strings, only on regexps with some additional restrictions. This will work:

```
awk -v tgt="$password" 's=index($0,tgt){$0 = substr($0,1,s-1) substr($0,s+length(tgt)}1' file
```

because it's using only string operations.

Given your newly posted information, you want this:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=":"} $1=="root"{$2=""} 1' shadowCopy.txt > tmp$$ &&
mv tmp$$ shadowCopy.txt
```

or if you have GNU awk and care about not naming the tmp file:

```
awk -i inplace 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=":"} $1=="root"{$2=""} 1' shadowCopy.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

It happens when your variable is resolved to an empty string. Look:

```
p="a" && sed "s/$p/?/g" infile
```

That yields:

```
J?n 16 08:33:18 m?il.
```

And:

```
p="" && sed "s/$p//" infile
```

That yields:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 0: no previous regular expression
```